# CSS выбор span:nth-child в выбранном li:nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
li::nth-child(7) span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 9px;
}
li::nth-child(7) span::nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="li1">1</li>
<li class="li2">2</li>
<li class="li3">3</li>
<li class="li4">4</li>
<li class="li5">5</li>
<li class="li6">6</li>
<li class="li7">
    <input id="in1" type="text" value="+"/>
    <span>span1</span>
    <span>s2</span>
    <span>s3</span>
</li>
<li class="li8">8</li>
```

Как бы должно выбрать 2 span в 7 li. Но не работает. В чем здесь ошибка?

Comment: У вас там 16, а не 7. Нет?

Comment: @Crantisz
Спасибо, исправляю..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так :

```
li:nth-of-type(16) span:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!! получилось!

Comment: Не подскажете, почему nth-child не работает, а с nth-of-type все хорошо?
PS: кто этому ответу минус поставил, за что!?

Comment: @CodeGust, минус можно поставить за отсутствие объяснения, почему это может помочь. И вообще, чем отличается приведенный код, от того, что в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy
да, тогда понятно. Не зря же у меня сразу коммент-вопрос появился...

Comment: @CodeGust разница данных методов в том что первый просто 'считает ' элементы а второй считает по типу, может прочитать http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-of-type

Comment: Впринципе два селектора этих почти ничем не отличаються , мне кажеться ошибка была в  2 символах :: т.к. для псевдокласса достаточно одного.

Comment: @s1mple. как это не отличаются? ))) я же привёл отличие, если у вас где то работали все методы, то у вас просто в html структуре было несколько 'одинаковых' элементов

Comment: @Arsen
Спасибо! теперь понятно, в чем была проблема в моем коде... ("первый просто 'считает ' элементы а второй считает по типу")

Answer (score 2):

Лишнее двоеточие `::` нужно только одно `:nth-child(7)`.

Двойное двоеточие может использоваться только в псевдо-элементах. А nth-child - это псевдо-класс.

```css
li:nth-child(7) span {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 9px;
}
li:nth-child(7) span:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="li1">1</li>
<li class="li2">2</li>
<li class="li3">3</li>
<li class="li4">4</li>
<li class="li5">5</li>
<li class="li6">6</li>
<li class="li7">
    <input id="in1" type="text" value="+"/>
    <span>span1</span>
    <span>s2</span>
    <span>s3</span>
</li>
<li class="li8">8</li>
```

Comment: почему нужно только одно? Зачем делать ответ общим?

Comment: да, здесь работает с одним. Но я пишу на stylus... в моем, более сложном варианте кода, nth-child не работает почему-то...хотя должно бы.

Comment: @Grundy Двойное двоеточие может использоваться только в псевдо-элементах. А `nth-child` - это псевдокласс. А сделал ответ общим, потому-что это не мой ответ

Comment: @Crantisz, а чей? В соседнем ответе про nth-of-type пример без каких либо объяснений

Comment: @Grundy s1mple заметил этот момент

Comment: В комментариях не считается :)

Comment: @Grundy Это дело автора вопроса, делать его общим или нет. После не поменяешь

Comment: @Crantisz, модераторы могут. Можно позвать

Comment: @Grundy http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2